# create table for multi valued attribute SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

[image]I need your support to check if the below code is correct for Emp_Ser table, where Emp_Ser table refers to multi valued attribute as the attached photo:

```
[![create table Employee(
Emp_id    number,
Emp_name    varchar2(10),
Emp_email    varchar2(30),
Emp_username    varchar2(11),
Emp_phone    number, 
primary key (Emp_id));

create table Service(
Ser_id    number,
Tool_sernum    number references Tools(Tool_sernum),
Ser_name    varchar2(15),
Ser_type    varchar2(10),
Ser_price    number,
primary key (Ser_id));

create table Emp_ser (
Emp_id    number,
Ser_id    number,
primary key (Emp_id, Ser_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK; although, I'd also create foreign key constraints from emp_ser to `employee` and `service`:

```
SQL> create table Emp_ser (
  2    Emp_id    number,
  3    Ser_id    number,
  4    primary key (Emp_id, Ser_id),
  5    constraint fk_es_emp foreign key (emp_id) references employee (emp_id),
  6    constraint fk_es_ser foreign key (ser_id) references service (ser_id)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```